# Take files from directory and insert content into SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop, fopen

I have 800+ text files in directory called documents. All have txt extension. from 100 to 500kb each file with text and html tags. Now i want import all files to my database. It's possible to do this with php? Also want to delete file.

I know only how to get filenames from dir but how to take content and insert into database?

```
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: .".$file."<br />";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Comment: Meaby best way will be put all filenames into array then foreach do file_get_contents??? Meaby is some more simple mode to import file content into database?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19965/109878

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load the contents of the file into a string and then write the string to sql

This will give you the contents of the file:

$fileContents= file_get_contents($file);

Comment: Just be sure to use PDO if doing this, otherwise you'll run into no end of issues, especially with that kind of data, definitely don't be tempted to concatenate the file contents into the query or make any attempt to escape chars, you'll end up in a right mess! PDO takes care of these problems for you